# For_each and count in same terraform AWS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create "***aws_route***" in terraform iterating over a list of route_tables with vpc_peering of another service. The other service vpc ***destination_cidr_block*** is a list.

```
variable "route_tables" {
  type        = set(string)
  description = "Set of route table entries eg : rt-1, rt-2 , rt-3"
}


variable "ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks"{
  type = list(string)
  description = "list of destination cidr blocks of external service, eg:[\"10.10.1.1/20\", \"10.2.10.1/10\"]"
}


resource "aws_route" "ext_service_route" {
 // iterating over route tables [ rt-1, rt-2 , rt-3 ]
  for_each = var.route_tables
  route_table_id = each.key

// Iterating over cidr list 
  count = var.ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks
  destination_cidr_block = var.ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks[count.index]
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.ext_service_peering_connection_id
}
```

[Here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route_tables), I would like to iterate over list of ***destination_cidr_block***.
Simply put, I need a nested loop, count inside for_each.
I can't have both count and for_each in the same block, is there any workaround for this?
Or is there any way I can split this into two modules?

Comment: You need to convert the `route_tables` into a Map and associate the cidr blocks with specific route tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`setproduct`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct) to compute the Cartesian product of those two collections and create a `map` based on that. This `map` can be used to do `for_each` on it:

```
resource "aws_route" "ext_service_route" {
  for_each                  = { for i, pair in tolist(setproduct(var.route_tables, var.ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks)) : "route-${i}" => { "name" : pair[0], "cidr" : pair[1] } }
  route_table_id            = each.value.name
  destination_cidr_block    = each.value.cidr
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.ext_service_peering_connection_id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mod` operation to iterate over the two lists simultaneously (for example, when you are using older TF version that does not support `for_each` yet):

```
resource "aws_route" "ext_service_route" {
  count                     = length(var.ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks) * length(var.route_tables)
  route_table_id            = element(var.route_tables, count.index + 1 % length(var.route_tables))
  destination_cidr_block    = element(var.ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks, count.index + 1 % length(var.ext_service_destination_cidr_blocks))
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.ext_service_peering_connection_id
}
```